# cloudflare button in cpanel is missing how to add it?

Tags: cpanel, cloudflare, whm

I have the latest WHM 96

in Many tutorials on the web they talk about this
[image]

but It's  brand new clean install and the "cloudflare" button is missing.

How do I install it ???

Comment: From the cpanel tag: Only PROGRAMMING related questions are on-topic. General configuration questions are off-topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is CloudFlare's cPanel plugin which requires a CloudFlare Partnership account, and is no longer supported by them:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042380772-Partner-Plugin-Supportability

If you really search around you'll find the Github repo for the plugin as well as installation instructions. But because it is no longer supported, I doubt that they'll activate the features for it on a new installation.